Question about JDK 22 / Jextract and their current status
I noticed that the April 30th build no longer has an "Known Issues" section like previous release.
Previous Known Issues Section
But I seems still have problem trying to compile some Vulkan header due to bitfield and other C struct not supported. Does anyone have some idea on the status of Jextract?
WARNING: Skipping VkAccelerationStructureSRTMotionInstanceNV.flags (bitfields are not supported)

WARNING: Skipping VkMicromapEXT_T (type Declared(VkMicromapEXT_T) is not supported)

WARNING: Skipping VkOpticalFlowSessionNV_T (type Declared(VkOpticalFlowSessionNV_T) is not supported)

WARNING: Skipping VkShaderEXT_T (type Declared(VkShaderEXT_T) is not supported)

Error message looks like this.
I was expecting the Jextract to work since they remove the known issues section in new release note.
Update: some experiment with GLFW3 and result
 import java.lang.foreign.*;
 import org.glfw3.java.*;


class GLFW_Java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("glfw3");
        System.out.print("Start");
        glfw3_h.glfwInit();
        try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
        String window_name_javaString = "Simple Example";
        MemorySegment window_name_C = arena.allocateFrom(window_name_javaString);
        MemorySegment window = (MemorySegment) 
        glfw3_h.glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, window_name_C, null, null);
        if (window != null) {
                System.out.print(window);
            }
        }
    }
}

Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: should not reach here
    at org.glfw3.java.glfw3_h.glfwCreateWindow(glfw3_h.java:4721)
    at GLFW_Java.main(GLFW_Java.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glfw3.java.glfw3_h.glfwCreateWindow(glfw3_h.java:4719)


We removed the known issues from that page. Instead they are listed in the guide now: https://github.com/openjdk/jextract/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#unsupported-features

FWIW, the latter 3 warnings can pretty much be safely ignored. They are just jextract saying that it encountered an opaque type. Is there a particular thing that you need when using Vulkan that's missing from the generated bindings?

@JornVernee Thanks for replying. The later 3 rows are not requirede for Vulkan AFAIK, but Jextract also skip other Vulkan struct and GLFWwindow for GLFW3 with """type Declared(GLFWwindow) is not supported""". GLFWwindow is a vital struct for whole  rendering pipeline, so I am having some real troubles integrate my C codes with Java.

I just checked the updated guide page. The problem was probably caused by the stuct being a opague type. I wonder if there will be a fix from Jextract some day near, or I might better off just mannually integrate C with Java using Arean and MemorySegement first. Java could be the perfect language for real-time simulation / game engine , just that making it work with C/cpp is way too hard.

As for opaque types: there is nothing on jextract's end to 'fix'. The library in question has chosen to use opaque types, that's all. Have you tried using the generated bindings?

@JornVernee I updated original post. Apologize for my lack of Jextract knowledge, still learning it. The code worked in C and should print out a memory address, but give out java.lang.NullPointerException in Java. I have also checked that the called function did not return Null in Java.

For passing NULL, you should use MemorySegment.NULL, instead of the Java null literal.

Thanks to JornVernee. Problem solved. GLFW3 now works smoothly with JDK22 and Jextract. Sample code below. 
1.Compile GLFW3 according to the official Jextract guide. 
2.then run Java with "-I" flag to include .dll/.dylib should run smoothly.
import java.lang.foreign.*;
import org.glfw3.java.*;


class GLFW_Java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("glfw3");
        System.out.print("Start");
        glfw3_h.glfwInit();
        try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
            String window_name_javaString = "Simple Example";
            MemorySegment window_name_C = arena.allocateFrom(window_name_javaString);
            MemorySegment window = (MemorySegment) glfw3_h.glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, window_name_C, MemorySegment.NULL, MemorySegment.NULL);
            if (window != null) {
                System.out.print(window);
            }

            glfw3_h.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

            while (glfw3_h.glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0) {
                glfw3_h.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
                glfw3_h.glfwPollEvents();
            }

            glfw3_h.glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            glfw3_h.glfwTerminate();

        }
    }
}

